# .Service File D-Bus

Tags: dbus

I'm trying to auto-start a DBus service when my client program starts. I've setup a .service file, but it's not working.

My service name is

```
org.fandingo.PMP
```

I register the name with a python server with

```
 name = dbus.service.BusName('org.fandingo.PMP', session_bus)
 object = PMPService(session_bus, '/PMPService', PMPProxy())
```

I can connect to this fine if I manually run the server code with the following from the client

```
remote = bus.get_object('org.fandingo.PMP', '/PMPService')
```

So the server and client both work if invoked manually. If I just try the client, I get the following Python exception

```
dbus.exceptions.DBusException: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.fandingo.PMP was not provided by any .service files
```

Here is my .service file

```
-rw-r--r--. root root unconfined_u:object_r:usr_t:s0   /usr/share/dbus-1/services/org.fandingo.PMP.service
```

These permissions and SELinux labels are identical to the other .service files.

The .service file contents

```
[D-Bus Service]
Name=org.fandingo.PMP
Exec=/home/fandingo/code/python/pmp/src/pmpserver.py
User=fandingo
```

pmpserver.py is executable and has the correct shebang.

Does anyone see any problems with me configuration?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally figured this one out.

I'm not sure exactly how .service files are executed, but they don't get /bin/env set properly.

My shebang was not working properly:

```
#!/bin/env python
```

I changed my service file to

```
[D-Bus Service]
Name=org.fandingo.PMP
Exec=python /home/fandingo/code/python/pmp/src/pmpserver.py
```

Everything works great now.

Comment: The more usual location for env is in /usr/bin. At least on Linux it's there.

Comment: To editors: please resist the temptation to fix the original shebang. That would make the comment and the reason why the activation initially failed more obscure.